# How to write data into Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation

I am trying to write user location data into our Firebase RDB with an interval of 2000 ms.
The console shows that we are getting the location data correctly ever 2 seconds. However, the data will not be transferred into our Firebase RDB.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**tracking.page.ts**

```
  // Start location watch
  watchLocation() {
    const options = {
      maximumAge: 15000,
      timeout: 5000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
    };
    this.isWatching = true;
    this.trackingId =  '-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 28);

    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.watchLocationUpdates = this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options);
    this.watchLocationUpdates.then((resp) => {

      this.geoLocations = resp.coords;
      this.geoLatitude = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.geoLongitude = resp.coords.longitude;
      this.geoAccuracy = Math.trunc(resp.coords.accuracy);
      this.timeStamp = resp.timestamp;

      this.geolocationService.insertUserGeolocation({
        trackingId: this.trackingId,
        latitude: this.geoLatitude,
        longitude: this.geoLongitude,
        accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
        timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
        uId: this.uId
        });
          console.log(`User location data inserted in FB`, {
            trackingId: this.trackingId,
            latitude: this.geoLatitude,
            longitude: this.geoLongitude,
            accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
            timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
            uId: this.uId
            });

      const position = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
      this.map.setCenter(position);
      this.map.setZoom(16);

      this.markers.map(marker => marker.setMap(null));
      this.markers = [];
        const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: this.map,
          icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 13,
            fillColor: '#1AA0EC',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeColor: 'white',
            strokeWeight: 2
        },
          position: latLng
        });
        this.markers.push(marker);
      });
    }, 2000);
}
```

**geolocation.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment  } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GeolocationService {
  databaseUrl = environment.firebase.databaseURL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello OrganizationService Provider');
    console.log('OrganizationService: ', this.databaseUrl);
  }

  insertUserGeolocation(data) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.databaseUrl}/geolocations/.json`, data);
    console.log('insertUserGeolocation(data): this.insertUserGeolocation(data));
  }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be checking for errors anywhere.  How would you know if a request fails for some reason?

Comment: The console.log doesn't throw any errors. All the location data is shown in the right way. But somehow it will not get transferred into the RDB.

Comment: You need to check for errors in your code and print the results to the console. You will need to figure out if `this.http.post()` fails.

Comment: You  mean like this? console.log(`User location data inserted in FB`, {
            trackingId: this.trackingId,
            latitude: this.geoLatitude,
            longitude: this.geoLongitude,
            accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
            timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
            uId: this.uId
            });

Comment: I don't know how the API works, but you should do whatever you need to do to figure out of the request fails. Please edit the question to include the code that checks for errors, and if there's an error message, include that as well in your question.

Comment: I added a console.log() to the insertUserGeolocation(data) function. But unfortunately it will not show up in the console. (Unreachable code detected.ts(7027))

Comment: I just found the solution. I will post it below. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. Please find the code below.

```
this.geolocationService.insertUserGeolocation({
        trackingId: this.trackingId,
        latitude: this.geoLatitude,
        longitude: this.geoLongitude,
        accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
        timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
        uId: this.uId
        }).subscribe((response) => {
          localStorage.setItem('lastLocation', JSON.stringify({
            trackingId: this.trackingId,
            latitude: this.geoLatitude,
            longitude: this.geoLongitude,
            accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
            timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
            uId: this.uId
            }));
          console.log(`user location data inserted in FB`, {
            trackingId: this.trackingId,
            latitude: this.geoLatitude,
            longitude: this.geoLongitude,
            accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
            timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
            uId: this.uId
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier and more efficient to use the library `AngularFire`, instead of using the `HttpClient` and doing an http request.

For rxample, you can add data by using the `push()` method:

```
const itemsRef = db.list('items');
itemsRef.push({ name: newName });
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/README.md#install

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about that too. But we might want to change the DB (e.g. Amazon Cloud) in the future and then it wont work with AngularFire anymore. Or am I wrong? Do you might have a solution for the issue I mentioned above as well?

Comment: Can u check the logs for any error, also are you using read and write rules equal to true?

Comment: I checkt the console for errors. Everything looks fine. All the console.logs are shown. Also the Firebase rules are right. I suppose it has something to do with the .then. I changed it from .subscribe while implementing the setInterval() function. Since then it wont work anymore.

Comment: Where are u subscribing in your code? The post returns an observable which you can subscribe to and add a console.log to check wat is happening

Comment: I subscribed before I added the setInterval() function. With the setInterval() function implemented the subscription was not working anymore. Thats why I changed it to .then.

Comment: I just found the solution. I will post it below. Thank you so much for your help! :)